# Can I make different browsers show HTML form error messages the same way?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation, constraint-validation-api

I have created a login form with username and password fields. Username should be a a text filed with type email and password will be a text filed with type password which need to satisfy a regex pattern.

Everything is working as expected. The issue I am facing is that when the user enters a invalid user name the error message is shown differently across different browsers as shown below.

**Internet Explorer**

[image]

**Google Chrome**

[image]

**Mozilla Firefox**

[image]

Is it possible to have a generic design for the error messages across browsers?

Comment: From experience I can tell you that each browser has it's own error message, I however do not know if you can override their messages.

Comment: It depends on browser. If you want to display in generic design, you need to use angular way of form validation ttps://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms (if you are using angularjs) or use third party form-validation plugins.

Comment: The only way to guarantee a generic design is to implement the validation yourself. But I must ask, is it really a problem? Most people use and stick to one browser, they'll be used to the look of the native error messages.

Comment: You use a css framework such as bootstrap and get the similar look and feels in all browsers

Comment: [setCustomValidity()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh441292.aspx) method of JavaScript may help you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot modify the default behavior, but You can use angular validation for that.

Something like this:

```
<form name="signUpForm">
            <div>
                <input name="email" type="email" required autocomplete="off" ng-model="formData.Email" />
                <div class="error-message" ng-show="signUpForm.email.$error.required">UserName is required</div>
                <div class="error-message" ng-show="signUpForm.email.$error.email">Not Valid Email</div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

then, you can customize error-message class as you want.
in order to show messages only when posting the form, some modifications need to be made, but you can get the idea.

see this: [Angular Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

and this: [Angular Forms Validation](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp)

for more info.